# Regarding Dynamic Partition Table insert without creating staging/temp table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

While loading data into Dynamic partition table I know first to create
    temp/staging table then load data in this temp table and then overwrite
    into partitioned table but in an interview I was asked how to load directly
    without temp/staging table.Please guide what are other methods to insert.

Comment: 1) copy data to hive table's location in a subdirectory `colName=value` 2) use `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` 3) PROFIT!

Comment: philantrovert will you explain with following exa. suppose I have Bowling dataset with 12 teams and partition is done on team as follows using temp table plz guide how to achieve without temp table,                                                   create table bowling_no_partition
(id int, name String, team String, overs float, runs int, wickets int, avg float, economy float, strike_rate float)

Answer (score 1):

To load the data directly in the table without using temp/staging table we can use the below command

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH 'filepath' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE db.tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```

[You can refer to the link](http://www.aodba.com/loading-data-into-apache-hive-using-load-command/)